# What is the built gemspec file (with version) for?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When I run the command

`$: gem build example_gem.gemspec`

I get a file called example_gem-0.0.0.gem.  What is in this file and what is it for?

Does this file play a part with how gems get included into Ruby code that requires them *once the gem is already installed* on the machine?

I noticed that when I go into my INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY, I can see the gems in folders with names matching matching the format of this versioned gem file, but inside the directory, I only see the other library code, gemspec file, etc.

Does this mean it is for uploading/downloading/installing only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.gem` file is, well, *the Gem*. It contains the Gemspec (more precisely, a `Marshal` serialized version of the object graph of the Gemspec, rather than the executable `.gemspec` while which *generates* that object graph) as well as a compressed archive of all the files that are part of that gem (listed in the Gemspec). It also contains a cryptographically secure checksum and an optional cryptographic signature.

When you install a `.gem`, RubyGems checks the cryptographic checksum to make sure the Gem was not tampered with, checks the optional signature to make sure the Gem was created by who you think it was, reads the Gemspec to figure out what to do with the Gem, and unpacks it into the `$GEM_HOME` directory.

`Kernel#require` simply goes through the search path until it finds a file matching the name you provided and *runs the file*. It knows nothing about Gems. (It *does* know how to *find* the unpacked Gem directory, though.)

[Note: this is somewhat simplified. `Kernel#require` may have implementation-specific features, for example, YARV's `Kernel#require` also knows how to load dynamic libraries (e.g. `.dll`s, `.so`s, `.dylib`s, depending on the OS), JRuby's `Kernel#require` also knows how to load `.jar`s, and so on.]

Comment: Using Bundler#require to require the gems in your Gemfile is generally better idea then using Kernel#require as it ensures that you get the correct version of the gem. Bundler does understand the gemspec and will also load the dependencies of the gem.